# add property to a string

Tags: javascript, string

Who can help me understand following code

```js
var  str = 'test1'
str.len = 4
var strlen1 = str.len
console.log('strlen1 = ', strlen1) // strlen1 =  undefined
var strlen2 = str.len = 4
console.log('strlen2 = ', strlen2) // strlen2 = 4
```

Why it got this output? Thank you

Comment: Because you have not define `str.len`, this is not right way to define variable

Comment: `str.len = 4` is not pointing to any reference.That's why in first case your output is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `str` is a string literal, `str.len = 4` is basically rendered as

```
var temp = new String(str);
temp.len = 4;
temp = null
```

As you can see any update applied were temporary and are not available after that line. Hence, as `str.len` is undefined, with `var strlen1 = str.len`, you assign `undefined` to `strlen1`

`var strlen2 = str.len = 4` is basically rendered as

```
var strlen2 = 4;
str.len = 4;
```

So as you can see there are 2 different assignment rather than 4 being assigned to `str.len` and then `str.len` assigned to `strlen2`

If you want to the first condition to work, make `str` a String object. Try following

```js
var  str = new String('test1')
str.len = 4
var strlen1 = str.len
console.log('strlen1 = ', strlen1) // will paint 4
```

Comment: thanks for your great explication，now i know string will be convert to String object automatically, but temp = null , where can i find provenance about it, can not find it in MDN

Comment: I got the answer from here: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/    thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a property to a Sting object you can do this :

```js
String.prototype.len = null;
var  str = new String('test1');
str.len = 4
var strlen1 = str.len
console.log('strlen1 = ', strlen1) // strlen1 =  4
```

And when you write

```js
var str = "test1";
var strlen2 = str.len = 4
console.log('strlen2 = ', strlen2) // strlen2 = 4
console.log('str.len = ', str.len) // strlen2 = undefined
```

`str.len` is still undefined

Answer (score 0):

`str.len = 4` **str** is a String so you can't set properties to it.

`var strlen2 = str.len = 4` **strlen2** is a normal variable that equals 4. here `str.len` still `undefined`

You would be able to do that as below code

```js
var x = 'this is string';

var data = {}

data.len = x.length;

console.log(data.len)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see, by testing that:

```
var  str = 'test1'
str.len = 4
console.log(str.len) // Undefined
```

That being said, you realize you can't add properties to a string. You probably want to use an object instead.

And btw, do you really need to add that '.len' there? Can't you use the string.length ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var z=undefined=4
console.log(z) //4
```

Your expression `str.len` will give undefined, You can not set a property to a string